# How can I send thousands of small amounts (10'000 sat.) to bitcoin wallets without paying to much fees?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, multi-signature, satoshi, faucets

I want to make a faucet. But my problem is that I don't know how I can make my payouts. I would have a lot of little amounts (like 10'000 satoshis) to pay.
Is there an efficient way of doing thousands of those transactions without paying to much fees?

Do I have to make every transaction manually (in Python or in Java with the Blockchain API)?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Note that the Bitcoin protocol is intentionally designed to make it expensive to do this - transactions are a scarce resource and making lots of them is going to cost you in fees, one way or the other.  Given the current controversies over block size and its effects, you might reconsider whether another new service to create huge numbers of small transactions is really in the best interests of the Bitcoin world right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic issue with faucets and thus there are services that can help you with this. E.g. check [this](https://paytoshi.org/faq)

Behind the scenes those services use send_many as you already found out.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the visitors, which have thought about that.
I found now the solution for that problem. I use the blockchain.info API. There is an option to send to many addresses at the same time.
https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-python/blob/master/docs/wallet.md

Comment: I am not sure that blockchain.info is the cheapest and easyest way to solve your problem. There are some restrictions, for example maximum number of outputs in one transaction is limited to 20 (or 40? - I do not remember).